# Problem booting Windows after failed installation of 12.04 alongside Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows, boot-failure

I tried to install in my laptop 12.04 so that I can dual-boot with Windows 7. I made some mistakes during this process and I didn't manage to install Ubuntu.
But my real problem now is that I'm afraid that I also destroyed the installation of Windows 7. Your help would be precious for me.

Here are the details of what I did:

1.) I followed [these instructions](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/) to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7.

The only difference from what is described above, is that in my case the device names where:

`/dev/mapper/isw_fdjdhbadc_Volume0*` instead of `/dev/sda*`

Note that I had created a bootable USB stick to do that.

2.) The installation proceeded normally, but in the end I got a fatal error because the grub-install failed.

3.) Then, after Googling this problem, I run Ubuntu from the USB stick and run this command:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/home/ubuntu/temp /dev/mapper/isw_fdjdhbadc_Volume0p5
```

(/isw_fdjdhbadc_Volume0p5 was the partition that I had made for /boot) but this command also failed.

4.) Then, I did something stupid (I think): I run the above command as:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/home/ubuntu/temp /dev/mapper/isw_fdjdhbadc_Volume0
```

namely I tried to install grub in the device `isw_fdjdhbadc_Volume0` instead of the boot partition `isw_fdjdhbadc_Volume0p5`

The above command did not fail and was executed OK.

5.) After that, I tried to boot my laptop, but it seemed that I had no operation system. Not even Windows were detected.

6.) I thought that I should uninstall **grub** from `isw_fdjdhbadc_Volume0`. So following some online instructions that I found, I booted again Ubuntu from the USB stick and run the following command (this was stupid since the instructions were for a totally different case than mine):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/isw_fdjdhbadc_Volume0  bs=446 count=1
```

Afte that, I was still unable to boot Windows. I realize that I deleted something that I shouldn't, but I'm hope that this is not crucial and I can recover somehow.

When I boot Ubuntu from the USB, I can see that the partition with Windows is still there, with all the directories, Windows files, my data etc.

So, my question is:
*Is there a way to undo the mistakes that I described above and recover Windows 7?*
This is my major question. After solving that, I'd also like to know what I did wrong with the installation of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Windows Installation disk and use the instructions [given here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/).

Comment: sriram pandey, thanks a lot for your link!

Let me clarify that I'm getting the following error when I open my laptop:

"Operating System Not Found"

Do you think that this case needs a different treatment than what is described to the link you sent (where the reported error is “BOOTMGR is missing”)?

Another question: It would be great if you could help me understand the following:
By using the "dd" command, did I delete crucial data from the windows partition, or from somewhere else (that can be recovered)?

Comment: If you follow these directions, you will not make it worse. If your description is ok.

Comment: Hi all,
Finally I solved the problem and managed to recover Windows 7.

I followed the instructions from the link of siriam pandey. 
I first tried the "Automated Startup Repair" as suggested in this link but it didn't work. Then, I tried the command-line stuff and it worked!

Thank you for your help and suggestions!!